# PHP Array from Database, set a row as Array title

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I got this code to fetch data from my Database to store in an Array in PHP:

```
<?php 
    $keyemail = "testmail@testmailer.com";
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM crypto_data WHERE email = '$keyemail'");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $myCoins[] = array($row['currency'], $row['amount'], $row['price_when_bought']);
    }

    var_dump($myCoins);
?>
```

The Array I get looks like this:

```
array(2) {
    [0] => array(3) {
        [0] => string(3) "BTC"[1] => string(1) "2"[2] => string(2) "23"
    }
    [1] => array(3) {
        [0] => string(3) "IOT"[1] => string(1) "6"[2] => string(2) "74"
    }
}
```

How can I change my Code to get the Array listed as below?
So that the $row['currency'] is the array Title of each Array.

```
array(2) {
    ["BTC"] => array(2) {
        ["balance"] => int(2) ["boughtprice"] => int(23)
    }
    ["ETH"] => array(2) {
        ["balance"] => int(6) ["boughtprice"] => int(74)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, it would really help if you have any code to share, what you have tried so far

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
$myCoins[] = array($row['currency'], $row['amount'], $row['price_when_bought']);
```

to

```
$myCoins[$row['currency']] = array('balance' => $row['amount'], 
                                   'boughtprice' => $row['price_when_bought']);
```

Comment: exactly what I needed, much appreciated